# getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load (URL) Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-apps

here am trying to get reccurring events from calendar list for sharepoint Online app and there am using code as like

```
hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    function GetListData() {
        var webUrl = hostWebUrl;// = "http://server/sitewhereyourlistexists";
        var listGuid = "{2000da75-8663-42d9-9999-ad855c54b4e0}"


        // An XMLHttpRequest object is used to access the web service
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");

        // The message body consists of an XML document 
        // with SOAP elements corresponding to the GetListItems method parameters
        // i.e. listName, query, and queryOptions
        var data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                "<soap:Body>" +
                "<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">" +
                        "<listName>" + listGuid + "</listName>" +
                        "<query>" +
                            "<Query><Where>" +
                                "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\"/>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\"/>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>" +
                                    "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today/></Value>" +
                                "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
                            "</Where></Query>" +
                        "</query>" +
                        "<queryOptions>" +
                            "<QueryOptions>" +
                                "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
                            "</QueryOptions>" +
                        "</queryOptions>" +
                "</GetListItems>" +
                "</soap:Body>" +
            "</soap:Envelope>";

        // Here we define what code we want to run upon successfully getting the results
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    var doc = xhr.responseXML;
                    // grab all the "row" elements from the XML results
                    var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
                    var results = "Today's Schedule (" + rows.length + "):\n\n";
                    var events = {};
                    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
                        var id = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_FSObjType"); // prevent duplicates from appearing in results
                        if (!events[id]) {
                            events[id] = true;
                            var allDay = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_fAllDayEvent"),
                                title = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_Title"),
                                start = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_EventDate");
                            var index = start.indexOf(" ");
                            var date = start.substring(5, index) + "-" + start.substring(2, 4); // get the date in MM-dd-yyyy format
                            start = start.substring(index, index + 6); // get the start time in hh:mm format
                            var end = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_EndDate");
                            index = end.indexOf(" "); end = end.substring(index, index + 6); // get the end time in hh:mm format
                            results += date + " " + (allDay == "1" ? "All Day\t" : start + " to " + end) + " \t " + title + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                    alert(results);
                } else {
                    alert("Error " + xhr.status);
                }
            }
        };

        // Finally, we actually kick off the query
        xhr.send(data);
    }
```

after calling this function in decument. ready section it is not retrieving any data but there is ine error which i can see in console of browser that is as below
[image]

Comment: Hi there, have you tried installing Fiddler and then running the POST again? Fiddler is a great network method debugging tool, you can see the requests and the responses. Please post back when you have tested so I can assist you further.

Comment: yes ,i have installed this now how do i debug my code with it?

Comment: You just need to have the app open (Fiddler) then execute the POST in your app and it will pickup on the network call

Comment: and what after that?means what next?

Comment: this is exactly what I'm getting -- calling web services in a sharepoint app (because of recurring events)..

Answer (score 0):

You will click on the correct request in the left hand side panel, then select "Inspectors" in the right hand side top panel. Then choose between the different request and response options.

[image: Fiddler]

Comment: okk,so what it supposed to show me,which is causing the above stated error?

Comment: Pretty much yeah -> else just debug your call to the server. Please post back what you find so I can assist further.